# Can't find the docker-compose.yml file

Tags: fscrawler

The documentation states:

And, prepare the following docker-compose.yml. You will find this example in the contrib/docker-compose-example-elasticsearch project directory.

Where do I find this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/tree/master/contrib/docker-compose-example-elasticsearch. I believe this is the example you are looking for.